# Polymer-cli : The localhost page isn’t working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

```
$ polymer serve -o
```

Chrome says :

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

but if I use : http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or http://api.local.host:8080/ (custom host in host file)

the Polymer App is rendered.

```
Node : 4.3.0 
Polymer-cli : 0.11
Bower : 1.7.9
OSX : 10.11.5
Chrome : 50.0.2661
```

Comment: That's odd. I'm assuming you already checked the host file for localhost rules. What's the output of `traceroute localhost`?

Comment: traceroute to localhost (127.0.0.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.230 ms  0.046 ms  0.055 ms

Comment: I can't reproduce this on OSX El Capitan, Node 4.4 or 6.2, Chrome 51.

Comment: I see that we don't have the same versions for Node & Chrome. Thanks anyway

Comment: @tony19 : Updated everything and it's still not working, but from what I saw on the different github repo, many ppl are having various problem right now, so I'll just wait for the next release ...